# Discord Bot That Is Able To Create Roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I need my discord bot to at a command (say !command) will create 3 roles (role one, role two, role three). It would be great if the roles could have colors and be hoisted but it's not necessary and I don't need anything beyond that. Nothing I've seen on Stack Overflow or Youtube has worked. Also, I'm using discord.js if that helps.

This is the code I've tried:

```js
guild.roles.create({ data: { name: "Role One", permissions: ["View_Channels"] } });
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You need to attempt this yourself. If you run into debugging issues, that's when you come to this site, show your code and explain the intended behavior

Comment: @Elitezen I added the code that isn't working.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Jakye I'm not getting any error, it's just not giving the role when the command is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The permission "VIEW_CHANNELS" doesn't exist, it is **"VIEW_CHANNEL"**

You can get all the role permissions here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS

Comment: (node:80) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: guild is not defined

That's the error I'm getting

Comment: add message before guild.roles.create to define which guild you want to add the role to.

In this case the guild that the message gets sent in. so the code should be message.guild.roles.create

Comment: Now it's saying 'message' isn't defined (node: 150). It looks like this: 

`if (command === "test") {
    msg.reply('your command has been recieved')
    message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: "Role One", permissions: ["View_Channel"] } });
    
  }`

Comment: I see that you have your message as msg instead. Try changing message to msg?

Comment: The command does the reply. But I changed the 'message' in 'message.guild.roles' to msg and now the error is (node:104) "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:"